# Need clarification of Invitation flow in WingTipGames

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm building an API to support user provisioning for other application teams around my company.  I have a decent understanding of custom policies and have reviewed the invitation flow in WingTipGames, however the sample app is at times hard to follow given the sheer amount of functionality it offers. I would appreciate some clarification around what features I can ignore, vs what is required to support my use case.

Use Case:

My API's `CreateUser` method creates the user in B2C with ADGraph, then should generate an invitation link that includes a signed JWT with the user's email address, and finally email the link to the recipient.  The new user will click the link, which should redirect them directly to the Invitation policy to reset their password.

Clarification Needed:

I'm struggling with simple generation of the Invitation link.  What's shown in the sample seems overly complex for my API.  In general I'm confused about the OIDC setup given that my API itself (while separately requiring callers to authenticate) will not be involved at all when the recipient clicks the invite link. And as this is an API not an MVC app, I wonder if the process can be stripped down vs the invitation flow in WingTipGames.

- Why is `ChallengeAsync` called in the `Invitation\Create` method? Presumably this is why we then land in the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event.  Is the challenge what is somehow intercepted and translated into the invitation link?
- Are the classes in `WingTipCommon` relevant here?  Namely the AspnetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect extensions, handler, and middleware.  Asking because users should never arrive at the API in response to clicking the invite link so perhaps the extra plumbing is unnecessary.
- Users will always be in a new browser and session when the click the redeem the invitation link, and will redirect directly to the policy (if I understand correctly).  Do I still need to worry about the `skipCorrelation` and XSRF handling?

Any other general suggestions around what to pull out of the sample and what to ignore to support my use case are appreciated.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wingtip Games application implements the following flows for invitations:

1. [An invitation link to an application endpoint](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Controllers/InvitationController.cs#L58). This invitation link contains the e-mail address of the invited user, an invitation expiration, and a HMAC-based signature. When the invitation link is opened, [the application endpoint](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Controllers/InvitationController.cs#L90) validates the HMAC-based signature and the invitation expiration and, if they are valid, then it redirects the invited user to the policy endpoint. This policy redirection contains [a signed JWT](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Startup.cs#L421) with the email address of the invited user.
2. [An invitation link to the policy endpoint](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Controllers/InvitationController.cs#L67). This invitation links contains [a signed JWT](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Startup.cs#L421) with the email address of the invited user.

I prefer and recommend the first flow for invitations because the application endpoint can implement the invitation logic before the invitation policy is run (e.g. the application endpoint can validate the invitation expiration and, if it isn't valid, then it can display an error message) as well as after the invitation policy has run (e.g. the application endpoint can display a success message).

To answer your specific questions:

> Why is `ChallengeAsync` called in the `Invitation\Create` method?

This is called for the second flow for invitations. It is called so that [the authentication middleware can generate the invitation link and send the invitation message](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Startup.cs#L509). It is implemented like this so that the application logic doesn't have to be aware of the application identifier, the policy identifier, or the redirection URIs that are required for the invitation link.

> Are the classes in `WingTipCommon` relevant here?

They are used to support the second flow for invitations. See the next answer.

> Do I still need to worry about the `skipCorrelation` and XSRF handling?

This is implemented for the second flow for invitations. As result of the invitation policy, Azure AD B2C issues an authentication response to the client application, where this authentication response is processed by the authentication middleware. Because the authentication middleware doesn't invoke the invitation policy (i.e. it is invoked by the invitation link), then [the authentication middleware must be configured](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Controllers/InvitationController.cs#L75) to disable the built-in checks for [correlation of an authentication request with an authentication response](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipCommon/AspNetCore/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/WingTipOpenIdConnectHandler.cs).

Comment: Ok, I'm leaning toward the first flow with a `Redeem` method on my API, then redirect to the policy.  

Re: use of `ChallengeAsync`, given that my API is in it's entirety dedicated to this onboarding process, I'm ok with the app logic being aware of the app id and policy id.  Do you think it straight forward to extract the redeem logic from the middleware to a simple method that can be called from the `Redeem` method?  I think that would greatly simplify my setup.

Comment: Hi @MarkArnold. The authentication middleware is purposed for a web app rather than API (i.e. it creates cookies for the nonce validation, etc.) but the actual logic for generating the redirection URL should be transferrable. You might have to consider how you handle an expired invitation if you don't have a user interface to show this error condition.